# Pass arguments to labels function in scale_y_continuous() with do.call() yields error

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels, do.call

I want to make a ggplot for which the y-axis labels are formatted by a pre-made list. I have found that if I pass arguments to the `labels` option in `scale_y_continuous()` function in ggplot directly it works fine, but if I pass them via `do.call` it throws an error, even though (I think) these are equivalent.

Here is an example:

```
library(scales) 
# make the list of arguments
fn_args = list(prefix = "$", big.mark = ",", decimal.mark = ".")

# print an example of a number formatted with these arguments using do.call()
do.call(number, as.list(append(x=10001, fn_args)))

##> [1] "P10,001S"

# print the same number but put the arguments directly in the function
number(10001, prefix = "P", suffix = "S", big.mark = ",", decimal.mark = ".")

##> [1] "P10,001S"
# Great -- they're identical, as expected.
```

```
# Now, let's make plots:

library(ggplot2)


# this works and produces a plot with the y-axis formatted nicely
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, cyl)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels=function(s) number(x = s, prefix = "P", suffix = "S", big.mark = ",", decimal.mark = "."))



# But this one doesn't work:
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, cyl)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels=function(s) do.call(number, as.list(append(x=s, fn_args))))

##> Error in `f()`:
##> ! Breaks and labels are different lengths
```

I don't understand why I'm getting this error, since I thought those two formulations were identical.

I'd appreciate anyone's insights!

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need a flattened `list` - In the OP's code, the `append` first argument is `x`, thus `x=s`, assumes it is the value passed for the 'x' argument and not a named vector.  We may need `scale_y_continuous(labels=function(s) do.call(number, append(list(c(x=s)), fn_args)))`

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, cyl)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels=function(s) 
       do.call(number, c(list(x=s), fn_args)))
```

Comment: Incredible! Thank you.

And I think I spotted the issue -- I thought that `append(x=s, fn_args)` made a named list with $x=s but apparently that one list element is unnamed. Weird.

Anyway, thanks again. Much appreciated!

Comment: @user1713174 you need the `c` to do the named vector i.e. `append(c(x = 10), fn_args)` instead of `append(x=s,..` also the `as.list` is not really needed

Comment: @user1713174 in addition, there is a conflict between the argument name in `append` and your vector i.e. the first argument is `x` so, when you specify `x=s`, it assumes that you are passing s for the `x` argument instead of getting a named vector.